# How to access enum Map in velocity html template?

Tags: java, enums, velocity

I want to access `java.util.EnumMap` in velocity Html template.

```
enum Test {
    HUMAN,
    ANIMAL;
}



EnumMap<Test, Integer> map = new EnumMap<>(Test.class);
map.put(Test.HUMAN, 100);
map.put(Test.ANIMAl, 0);
responseData.setMap(map);
```

in html....

```
$!{responseData.(HUMAN)}; //dont work.
```

Is Velocity template only can get Map's value through String or Number key ?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I suggest to put in the context the element of the enum : `ctx.put("humanEnum", Test.HUMAN);` and then in your velocity template : `$responseData.get($humanEnum)`

Comment: What is `responseData` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I am sure concerning `Velocity` and java enums (say `vc` is the `VelocityContext`) : you can put an enum value in the context and use it normally in a velocity template (including as a key for an `EnumMap`) :

```
vc.put("human", Test.HUMAN);
map.put(Test.HUMAN, 100)
vc.put("map", map)
```

- `$map[$human]` gives `100`
- `$human.name()` gives `HUMAN`
- `$human.ordinal()` gives `0`

But I found no solution to use directly `$Test.HUMAN` in the template (`vc.put("Test", Test.class)` is accepted but in template `$!{Test.HUMAN}` is empty).